# How to plot a line with segments of different alpha values?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, plot, alpha

I want to plot a line in 3D and each segment of the line should have different alpha values. Afterwards i will render a video, where each frame has a different alpha value configuration. So in each frame a different part of the curve is shown (with ends fading out).
However, the alpha argument does not allow lists.

```
fig = plt.figure()
alphas = [0]*len(values)
ax = fig.gca(projection="3d")
ax.plot3D(np.arange(0, len(values)), values, 0, alpha=alphas)
plt.show()
```

The code produces following error:

> TypeError: alpha must be numeric or None, not <class 'list'>

So my question is how to achieve this?

matplotlib version is: 3.4.2

Comment: how many line segments do you have? you could try looping: `for alpha in alphas: ax.plot3D(range(len(values)), values, 0, alpha=alpha)`

Comment: I did that, however it does not work well. the lines are overlapping at the end of each segment and look less transparent than the rest.

Comment: the curve contains like 1000 points